# How to break a while loop when reached limits on Twitter's API?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am coding a program to get the followers from a given user, then use the follower's list to get their followers and so on. The code I have so far is as I show below:

```
import tweepy
import time
#insert your Twitter keys here
consumer_key ='key'
consumer_secret='secret'
access_token='accesstoken'
access_secret='accesssecret'

auth = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

list= open('/home/acrocephalus/GitHub/TweetViz/list.txt','w')

if(api.verify_credentials):
    print '-------------------------\n*** You are logged in ***\n-------------------------'

#Set starting Twitter handle
username = ['moixera']

user = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name=username).items()

#Set the number of levels to follow
depth=3

#Start extracting each level followers
while depth != 0:   
    for handle in username:
            print '\n\n Getting followers from: @' + handle+'\n\n'   
            user = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name=handle).items()
            while True:
                try:
                    u = next(user)
                    list.write(u.screen_name +'\n')
                    print u.screen_name
                except:
                    time.sleep(15*60)
                    print 'We have exceeded the rate limit. Sleeping for 15 minutes'
                    u = next(user)
                    list.write(u.screen_name +'\n')
                    print u.screen_name
            username = list.read().splitlines()
            print 'Moving to next username'
            depth = depth-1
list.close()
```

The problem is that it starts with the first user, gets her followers but doesn't continue with her followers list. I think that the problem is in the `while` loop. When it finishes getting the followers it jumps to the `except` part. The desired behaviour would be that when it has finished retrieving followers it jumps to the beginning of the `for` loop. The program should jumpt to the `except` part of the `while` loop when it reaches the Twitter's API hit limit and thus times out for 15 minutes. Can anyone help?
Cheers!

Dani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `for` loop instead of the `while` loop:

```
user_list = open('/home/acrocephalus/GitHub/TweetViz/list.txt','w')

for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name=handle).items():
    user_list.write(user.screen_name +'\n')
    print user.screen_name
```

N.B. don't use `list` as a variable name because it hides the `list` builtin.

I think that the API has some support for rate limiting, although I don't see it detailed in the documentation. You can enable it when initialising with [`tweepy.API()`](http://tweepy.readthedocs.org/en/v3.3.0/api.html?highlight=wait_on_rate_limit#tweepy-api-twitter-api-wrapper), see `wait_on_rate_limit` and `wait_on_rate_limit_notify`:

```
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
```

A very quick glance at the source code suggests that the API will figure out an appropriate waiting period based on headers returned from Twitter, e.g. `x-rate-limit-reset`, but I have not used this API so I can't be sure whether it works.

There are other problems with your code, however, these go beyond your question.

Comment: Thanks mhawke, I'll try your suggestions. Which other problems do you see?

Comment: No worries. I can confirm that the api will wait when the rate limit is reached. Other problems:  depth handling as pointed out by @tswei; the user list file is opened write only, thus the subsequent `username = list.read().splitlines()` will fail. Even if opened in append mode, you need to seek(0) the file then read to the point where the first unprocessed user is. I don't think that a file is useful here, perhaps a list or dict would be better.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit what do you mean with seek(0)?

Comment: Thanks mhawke. I've tried your solution and it works. Now I am dealing with the looping over the retrieved usernames.